# How do we edit Meta Tags for ArticleDetail Template pages in Community?

Tags: community, metadata, napili

I cannot Add or edit Meta Tags for Article Detail Template pages in Community.This is happening only for Article Detail Template Page.Is there any considerations on this...

**Edit Meta Tags options Available:**
[image]

**Edit Meta Tags options not Available:**
[image]

Do we have any Restrictions for Article Detail Template page to edit meta tags in community...?

Comment: As far as I can see, it seems to be not available for few particular types of Pages, specifically for Article, Feed, Question and Topic and that's because they are already optimized for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

*Meta Tags* are properties for [Search Engine Optimization (SEO)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo.htm&type=5). So as long as you have the option of providing SEO properties for a Page, you will see the option to edit the tags. And along with that you will also find other properties, viz., Title and Description there.

If you hover over to the info icon on meta tag, you will see that information as below.

> Optionally add <*meta*> tags to your page. These are used to provide information to search engines, browsers, and web services.

[image]

---

If you see the other pages, e.g., *Contact Support*, it allows you to set properties for SEO. Whereas in case of *ArticleDetail*, you will notice the text there which says, it has already been configured.

> The search engine optimization (SEO) properties are automatically configured for this page

With what I see in the Community builder, the SEO option is not applicable/available for Pages of type:

- Article Detail
- Feed
- Question
- Topic